# From Euler to Poisson equation: calculus identities suggestions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, poissons-equation

Kind of things that I always find in books and I never remember.

I am looking for a simpler/expanded form of the LHS of the following poisson equation in the case $ \nabla \cdot \underline v =0$

$$
\rho\nabla \cdot ( (\underline v \cdot \nabla) \underline v) = - \Delta p
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not the usual Poisson equation...  By rewritting the left hand side in cartesian coordinates, you get :

$$\nabla \cdot ((v\cdot \nabla)v )= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(v_i \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}  \right)$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}  + v_i\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}  $$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}  + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \frac{\partial} {\partial x_i } \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_j} \right)  $$

Now, by rewritting $\nabla\cdot v = 0$ in cartesian coordinate, you get $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_j}  = 0$

So this means that

$$\nabla \cdot ((v\cdot \nabla)v )=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}$$

Edit : you can note this with the double dot product

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} = \nabla v : (\nabla v)^t$$